# HTTPS with Passport-Local-mongoose in Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, passport.js, passport-local

Anyone experiencing the error in heroku? i am having MissingUsernameError
when i register user using postman to https link, when i use HTTP locally but with remote database(mLab) it works fine, anyone with the same issue?

am using these npm packages

```
"body-parser": "~1.18.2",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"dotenv": "^4.0.0",
"ejs": "^2.5.7",
"express": "~4.15.5",
"express-jwt": "^5.3.0",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"heroku-ssl-redirect": "0.0.4",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
"mongoose": "^4.12.5",
"morgan": "~1.9.0",
"multer": "^1.3.0",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^4.4.0",
"path": "^0.12.7",
"randomstring": "^1.1.5",
"serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"

//register user
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
var userAccount = new Account({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    company: req.body.company,
    active: true
});

Account.register(userAccount,req.body.password, function (err, account) {
    if(err){
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'registration of the user failed',
            error: err 
        });
    }else{
        passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
            req.session.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'registration of the user failed',
                        error: err
                    });
                }else{
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        message: 'user registered successfully'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        } 
    }
);
```

});

The response i have is this below.

```
{
"success": false,
"message": "registration of the user failed",
"error": {
    "name": "MissingUsernameError",
    "message": "No username was given"
}
```

}

Comment: http locally works fine as am able to register users with a remote database(mlab). I am 100% sure username and password paramters are passed and they are correct, since it works with HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
username: req.body.username,
```

should be

```
name: req.body.username,
```